# Считывание из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Имеется txt файл ,в котором на 1-ой строке указано количество файлов. Следующие N строк содержат названия файлов ,размер которых не более 32 символов (расширение "c").Необходимо считать каждый файл провести "преобразования" и результат сохранить в файл с расширением "wc"(имена совпадают).

Не создает некоторые из файлов.Подскажите что здесь исправить или как переделать.Спасибо.

```c
int main()
{
    FILE* start_FILE, * first_FILE, * second_FILE;
    int j,i,n,m;
    char nazvanie_FILE[35];
    start_FILE = fopen("project.txt", "r");
    m=fscanf(start_FILE, "%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            m = fscanf(start_FILE, "%s", nazvanie_FILE);
            j = 0;
            while (nazvanie_FILE[j] != '.') j++;
            first_FILE = fopen(nazvanie_FILE, "r");
            nazvanie_FILE[j + 1] = 'w';
            nazvanie_FILE[j + 2] = 'c';
            nazvanie_FILE[j + 3] = '\0';
            second_FILE = fopen(nazvanie_FILE, "w");
        }
}
```

Comment: Что за режим `wt`?

Comment: должен быть просто "w".Запускал с ним

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот работающий код для вашей задачи.

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_NAME 36

int main()
{
    FILE* start_FILE, * src_FILE, * dest_FILE;

    char src_file_name[SIZE_NAME];
    start_FILE = fopen("project.txt", "r");

    size_t quantity_files;
    fscanf(start_FILE, "%d", &quantity_files);
    if (NULL == start_FILE)
        return 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < quantity_files; i++)
    {
        fscanf(start_FILE, "%s", src_file_name);

        src_FILE = fopen(src_file_name, "r");
        if (NULL == src_FILE)
            return 1;

        size_t current_index = 1;
        while (src_file_name[current_index] != '.') current_index++;

        src_file_name[current_index + 1] = 'w';
        src_file_name[current_index + 2] = 'c';
        src_file_name[current_index + 3] = '\0';

        dest_FILE = fopen(src_file_name, "w");
        if (NULL == dest_FILE)
            return 1;

        /* Тут могут производиться ваши "преобразования" над данными из исходного .c файла*/

        //После работы с файлом, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО его закрывайте
        fclose(src_FILE);
        fclose(dest_FILE);
    }

    //После работы с файлом, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО его закрывайте
    fclose(start_FILE);

    return 0;
}
```

Из рекомендаций могу дать следующие:

1. Старайтесь более грамотно и понятно именовать переменные:

   - не использовать транслит (nazvanie_file и тд),
   - более точно описывать предназначение объекта (вместо first_FILE – src_FILE, например. src - source, ресурс, источник).
2. Объявляйте и инициализируйте переменные перед их непосредственным использованием, насколько это возможно.
3. ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО закрывайте файлы после окончания работы с ними! **fclose();**
4. Используйте именованные константы вместо "магических значений" - **const, #define**.
5. Когда что-либо выделяете для указателя – проверяйте всё ли хорошо прошло, посредством сравнения указателя с NULL.

   - `if (NULL == ptr) ...`

Если будут вопросы по коду - пишите.

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно понимаю size_t для безопасности, т.е большого количества файлов?

Comment: И ещё если название состоит из двух и более слов или в нём присутствует точка, он же не откроется. Тогда нужно посимвольное считывание?

Comment: @Skaze, ```size_t``` - это ```typedef unsigned long```, используется для явного указания типа, который связан с адресацией памяти (не существует отрицательных или не целых адресов) или просто того, что представляет исключительно беззнаковое целое число, например, количество чего-либо как у меня в коде: ```size_t quantity_files```. 

У size_t много фишек, погуглите, есть несколько хороших статей на эту тему.

Comment: @Skaze, по поводу точки. Да, здесь может быть ошибка, если точка встретится раньше точки перед расширением файла или будет несколько точек. Чтобы это как-то контролировать можно сделать дополнительную проверку на то, является ли первый символ после точки 'c', а второй символом окончания строки '\0'

Comment: А по пробелу? fscanf считает только до него же.Например file file.c

Comment: @Skaze, как вариант – попросить пользователя не использовать пробелы в названиях)
Если же как-то учитывать это дело, то можно посимвольно обрабатывать, пока окончание строки не встретится. Но это уже другая история

Comment: Просто обрабатывая посимвольно первый файл проходит,а второй имя которого больше обрывается на '\0'.Не заменяется на другой символ.